# Problem executing Angular Universal with lodash-es as a dependency

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli

I am converting my existing Angular project with an Express backend to Angular Universal. I am facing an error

```
<Project>\node_modules\lodash-es\cloneDeep.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import baseClone from './_baseClone.js';
                                                              ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:616:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.lodash-es/cloneDeep (<Project>\dist\server\main.js:10303:18)
```

From [What is the right way to use lodash-es in Angular Universal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47717245/what-is-the-right-way-to-use-lodash-es-in-angular-universal) I understand that I need to "whitelist" `lodash-es`. Thus, I installed `@angular-builders/custom-webpack` to modify my `angular.json`. I created a webpack config as such

```
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');

module.exports = {
    externals: [
        nodeExternals({
            whitelist: [/^lodash-es/]
        })
    ]
}
```

and modified my `angular.json` as

```
"architect": {
    "server": {
      "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:server",
      "options": {
        "customWebpackConfig": {
          "path": "./universal-webpack.config.js",
          "mergeStrategies": { "loaders": "replace" }
        },
        "outputPath": "dist/server",
        "main": "src/main.server.ts",
        "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.server.json"
      }
    }
```

I am on Angular CLI 6 and `ng eject` is blocked thus I cannot verify the generated webpack but the above attempt does nothing to fix the error.

**Note:** The server is coded in js and not Typescript so although `main.server.ts` undergoes a webpack build the express server itself is not manipulated by webpack in any way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an error in the webpack merge configuration.

```
"customWebpackConfig": {
    "path": "./universal-webpack.config.js",
    "mergeStrategies": { "externals": "replace" }
}
```

is the correct configuration object where I replaced `"mergeStrategies": { "loaders": "replace" }` with `"mergeStrategies": { "externals": "replace" }`